# How to add *.less to IIS 7.0?

Tags: css, iis-7, less

I have set up a virtual application on my localmachine and it is running but it's not loading the CSS file. And I am using the [lessCSS](http://lesscss.org/) for styling my application and I think the reason here for not loading the css here is that LESSCSS style sheet uses .less extension.

So what to do in order to read *.less file extension?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

There is no need to add a handler. Just add a MIME type (now known as Internet Media Type) for `.less` and set the MIME type to `text/css`.

Web servers see the extension of requests (just like extensions of files). If they know the extension, they serve the file, and add an HTTP Header Field to indicate that the content of the file is in which format. For example, when they serve static HTML files, they add `Content-Type: text/html` header field. This way, browsers can understand to use which application for processing the body of response.

If web servers don't know the request extension, they search to see if there is already another application installed on them which knows the extension. If there is another application, then they let that application serve the file.

You can think of this example to fully understand what happens:

You go to a restaurant, (you are the `HTTP request`). You ask for a pizza (pizza is the extension). The chef knows how to serve pizza, thus it serves you.

Now consider that you go to the same restaurant another time, and ask for `Bomyhoor` (a fake food). Chef doesn't know how to cook and serve that. He/she asks other cooks to see if there is already someone else in the kitchen (kitchen is the web server) who knows how to cook that? If someone knows ho to cook `Boomyhoor`, then he/she serves you.

Now, consider that you go another time, and this time ask for `Graboori`. Chef already knows (from a dictionary) that `Graboori` is just another name for Pizza. Because he knows how to server pizza, he simply serves that.

When you add a MIME type to a web server, you simply map a request extension to a file type.

Comment: I think the OP was asking about using a custom HTTP handler to do the transform server-side. But, your answer is correct if using the less.js client-side method.

Comment: This is SUPER heavy to do on the fly for every single user. The OP was looking for an auto-compiler so when you're done editing the .less (and save it) it compiles it into a CSS file and puts it in the right location. Eclipse has a plug-in for development, and I know you can set up apache on load up to do that for you with less commands on a linux box, but as for IIS it looks like you'll have to use a local compiler, or dedicate a service to it.

Comment: Please note that your webserver may return HTTP error code 406 - not acceptable if you define the mime type as text/css. You should use text/less as the mimetype.

Comment: dotless is the way I would handle it if you're using ASP.NET; otherwise the client lib (less.js) works fine.

Comment: @MaayanGlikser I spent hours searching the internet for that.  Everyone says set up a mimetype of text/css.  I finally fixed my 406 by putting `text/less`

Comment: To add to the comment by @Domenic, IF you looking to pre-compile your LESS and IF you are using Visual Studio, I would highly recommend Web Essentials (http://vswebessentials.com/). It will compile LESS on save, and you can just serve up the resulting CSS.

Answer (score 1):

you must add

```
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/css" />
</staticContent >
```

to your Web.config

sample :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/css" />
    </staticContent >
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="WordPress: http://YourSite.com" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
          <match url="*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```