# Is .less css extension supported in IIS 5.1?

Tags: asp.net

I have deployed a web site in IIS 5.1 which has .less extended CSS.The application runs fine but the CSS are not getting applied from .less extension.So whether .less extended CSS is supported in IIS 5.1?

Thanks in advance
Channakeshav

Comment: I think what applies to the new IIS applies to the old too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319555/how-to-add-less-to-iis-7-0

Comment: Hi Schlingel, I tried with all options,but not able to render the .less CSS in IE 8.So is IIS version problem?

Comment: Do you want your IIS to compile the less to CSS or do you want to get the JS-less-interpreter working? If the latter you have to include es5-shim.js. (It's no longer added to the less download.)

Comment: Yes IIS 5.1 should compile less to CSS

Comment: Did you add the dotless handler to your IIS? https://github.com/dotless/dotless/wiki/Using-.less