# Compile Sass files in IIS7

Tags: css, iis, iis-7, sass, webdeploy

I have encountered a problem in compiling Sass (.scss) files on IIS7. Is there any simple way to invoke the compilation? I have tried to [add the MIME type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319555/how-to-add-less-to-iis-7-0) but it wasn't working. Do I have to install something additional to IIS server?

I have also installed Mindscape instead of SassyStudio ad-on to Visual Studio and it did help because of dynamic .scss compilation. As you save .scss file, Mindscape generates .css file. But is there a posibility to run such compilation during deployment or on the IIS server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly Sass is a pre-processor, therefore must to be compiled to CSS to be used by the browser and IIS.

You have a few options:

1. Compile to css within Visual Studio and add the CSS to the project.
2. Have your build server/process compile to CSS before deploying to your environment. A common way to do this is with a Grunt or Gulp script.
3. Use [BundleTransformer for Sass](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.SassAndScss/1.6.9) and create bundles with your `.scss` files. The transformer will output the bundle compiled to CSS.

Comment: Do you have any sample projects with Sass/Scss implementation? I have been trying to make it work since your answer without any good results. [It's just not working...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36311750/sass-scss-by-bundletranslator) And as I see, [not only me can't get it working properly.](https://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/workitem/109)