# Sass SCSS by BundleTranslator

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, sass, bundletransformer

I have set up the **BundleTranslator** in my **MVC 5** project via **NuGet** (BundleTransformer.SassAndScss v1.9.96 with the Core and LibSassHost components). Next I have added the bundle reference to my View.cshtml

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/sass")
```

and redefined the **BundleConfig.cs**:

```
var nullOrderer = new NullOrderer();
var commonStylesBundle = new CustomStyleBundle("~/Content/sass");
commonStylesBundle.Include("~/Content/Custom/the-style.scss");
commonStylesBundle.Orderer = nullOrderer;
bundles.Add(commonStylesBundle);
```

After build, the website has a .scss reference:

```
<link href="/Content/Custom/the-style.scss" rel="stylesheet">
```

and everything is working locally probably only because I have installed **SassAndCoffee** package with **SassyStudio**. The problem emerges when I deploy on external IIS server. The file exists in the Content/Custom directory, but the website is broken. The HTML code also has the file reference (it links to .scss file, not compiled .css) but if I try to navigate to it, I get error 500.

I have changed the Sass file **Build Action** to *Content* (from *None*) and left **Copy to Output Directory** as *Do not copy*. I have also added httpHandlers to Web.config (but I actually don't know whatfor) but still nothing helps.

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="*.sass" verb="GET" type="BundleTransformer.SassAndScss.HttpHandlers.SassAndScssAssetHandler, BundleTransformer.SassAndScss" />
  <add path="*.scss" verb="GET" type="BundleTransformer.SassAndScss.HttpHandlers.SassAndScssAssetHandler, BundleTransformer.SassAndScss" />
</httpHandlers>
```

I didn't check all of the settings in **Web.config** because of the NuGet installation which (as I see) provides this kind of data for the BundleTransformer.

How do I configure the **BundleTransformer** to work correctly on **IIS**? Do I have to override the **BundleResolver** as [in example code](http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples%20of%20usage)?

```
BundleResolver.Current = new CustomBundleResolver();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things to try to diagnose the problem. Firstly it works locally! :)

**1.**
It is worth testing that your bundling works correctly. You can do this by temporarily setting the following (take this out once you have finished).

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;

        // Bundles and stuff...
    }
}
```

Run the site and then in your browser dev tools you should get something like this:

> /bundles/commonStyles?v=BzJZwKfP1XV8a6CotGRsHhbxraPDst9zDL2X4r36Y301

If this works then we can be happy bundling will work in production.

**2.**
Permissions. If your getting a 500 internal server error, check the permissions on the folder that contains the `scss` files. Also check they are there :)

**3.**
Mime type. There may be a slight chance that IIS needs a mime type added for `.scss`, but I'm not convinced it will.

Comment: It seems that it was the fault of step 1. Without `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` it's just not working. Thank you for your help! :) I have also discovered something like this [Delegate Sass Builder](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Delegate.SassBuilder) which requires no external dependencies/references and compiles .sass/.scss to .css with every build, but the CSS files are not being added to the project tree, so they are absent after deploy (if improved, I'd prefer this builder over the bundler). Also when EnableOptimizations was set to true, every CSS file had to be bundle included